# Is it possible to define set [ i ] in java and extract i th row from excel to that set? I checked this a lot in net but couldn't find

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

// Assigning values to set from sheet1  1 st row  data from columns  4 and 5 to a listofIntends[1],   2 nd row  data from columns  4 and 5 to a listofIntends [2], and so on till 
//  listofIntends[10]

```
     Set setofIntends = new HashSet();
     Set speedycheck = new HashSet();
     int ircount = 10;
     int iccount = 5;
     for (int y = 1 ; y <= ircount ; y++) {
       for ( int z = 4 ; z <= iccount ; z++) {
                 XSSFCell cellValue = sheet1.getRow(y).getCell(z);
                  String str_cellValue = cellValue.getStringCellValue();
                  setofIntends[y] = setofIntends[y].add(str_cellValue);
```

//is it possible to define setofIntends[1] for first row's data ..etc ,

Answer (score 1):

`Set` is not an array. It is an interface that defines exactly what you can do with the set. So, `Set` does not even allow accessing elements by index.

Moreover `Set` is a collection that **stores only unique objects**, that is why you cannot just put anything by index. `Set` implementation only allows you to "add" element and it takes care of maintaining element uniqueness within the set.

I would suggest you to use arrays straight away or `List` implementations if you need accessing your elements by index

Comment: Thnx I will check